# Is $(x+3)^2$ a trinomial or binomial since it can be expanded to $x^2 + 6x + 9$?

Tags: polynomials

If it can be expanded into a trinomial, is $(x+3)^2$ a trinomial? Or is it a binomial in its shortened form and only a trinomial when expanded?

Comment: Shortly, as it is stated in the answer, it's a square binomial or, with other words, trinomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, explicitly, a polynomial takes the form

$$a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots + a_n x^n$$

Thus, the expression $(x+3)^2$ does not fit into this form until you expand it out into $x^2 + 6x + 9$. Thus, since it fits the form above for a polynomial, and has three terms, we would indeed call it a trinomial.

The best you could get otherwise is that $(x+3)^2$ is the square of a binomial.

Comment: You have told the OP that $(x + 3)^2$ is not a polynomial. I don't think that bizarre advice will help him or her very much, since $(x + 3)^2$ certainly is a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

It's a "trinomial" formed from "binomial" expansion. For ease, just stick with "polynomial".